# Using a loop until it meets a cell border

Tags: vba, loops, border

Hi I have a simple question (it seems simple) and put a code as exemple. So I got a column with 1 number, and in the second column there is many number associated to this number (no merged cells).  In the second column, there is a border at the bottom of the last number.  How can I use a loop until it meets this border.  The numbers of numbers is different each time..thats why..
 In the second loop, i wrote "first_BORDER" at the place where i want to get the end of the loop.

```
Sub border()


Dim mpd As Worksheet
Dim ins As Worksheet
Set mpd = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ins = Sheets("CFM")

 For i = 1 To 1500

 For j = i To "first_BORDER"
ins.Cells(j + i-1, 17) = mpd.Cells(j + i-1, 17)

 Next
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
Sub border()

Dim mpd As Worksheet
Dim ins As Worksheet
Set mpd = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ins = Sheets("CFM")
'checks if border has been reached
Dim flag As Boolean

For i = 1 To 1500

'For j = i To "first_BORDER"
j = 1
    While flag = True
        If Range(Cells(j + i - 1, 17), Cells(j + i - 1, 17)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlContinuous Then
            ins.Cells(j + i - 1, 17) = mpd.Cells(j + i - 1, 17)
            j = j + 1
        Else
            flag = False
        End If

    Wend

Next
End Sub
```

instead of using the for j = 1 to ''' I've used a *while* loop. Whenever a border is found the flag value is changed to false. If the border is not found, j is incremented by "1". You could use the macro recorder to figure out this code. Instead of just looking for a border you could look for a specific type of border (thick, continues, ....). I've written an article in  my blog explaining how you could use the macro recorder to get the code for formatting purposes, [Using the macro recorder to format cells and range](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/21/excel-vba-formating-cells-and-ranges/)

Comment: np, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub StopAtBorder()
    Dim i As Long

    Do
        i = i + 1
        Range("B" & i).Value = "Over the bottom"
    Loop Until Range("B" & i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone
End Sub
```